# Giving a size to a loaded picture

Tags: image, qt, size

Is there an easy way to give a size to a picture we load or do we have to change the size of the picture before using it in Qt?

What I want is my image to take 10% of my scene, and be localised in the right bottom corner (for instance).

I have seen some questions/answers about that topic but there should be an easiest way than loading it in a QPixmap in a QLabel ...

I'm not using any layout, I juste have a `QGraphicsView` which fills my `MainWindow`. I just want my picture to be here (x,y) and to have this size (w,h) in my scene.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing paint event after loading a pixmap?

```
 void mapwidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawPixmap(int x, int y, int w, int h, pixMap);
}
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do with **paintEvent**. It will only paint when update or something is called, or I want my picture to be there, all the time. I'll probably need this function when I'll want my window to be resizable.

Comment: If you implement a resizeEvent and call update() it will always paint the image, so it will be there all the time.

Comment: That's helpful, for the next step. But I was just wondering with this question if there was a method or something to resize once a Pixmap, like setGeometry for a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use a QLabel as a frame and load your pixmap into the label for easy size manipulation and positioning.

```
QLabel *label = new Label;
QPixmap pic("C:/Users/Pic_Location.png");
label->setPixmap(pic);
label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);
```

From there you can grab the active scene size and resize the label as needed.